# java.time.LocalDateTime (also ZonedDateTime). Fails to return one year backward when minus 1 month with formatting

Tags: java

I'm doing this

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit


LocalDateTime doy = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.of(doy.getYear(), doy.getMonth(), doy.getDayOfMonth(),0,0,0,0);
d.plus(-1,ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
return d.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"))
```

`d` contains `2016-12-28T08:00:00.000Z` I want to get `2015-12-28T00:00:00.000Z`

I'm on mac OSX `java SE 8 1.8.0_45` also tried `java SE 8 1.8.0_72`

What am I doing wrong ?

**Adding more explanation here**

Apparently part of my problem is related to formatting

```
ZonedDateTime doy = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime d = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(doy.getYear(), doy.getMonth(), doy.getDayOfMonth(),0,0,0,0),ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(d.plus(-1,ChronoUnit.MONTHS));
System.out.println(d.minusMonths(1));
System.out.println(d.plus(-1,ChronoUnit.MONTHS).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")));
```

output

```
2016-01-28T00:00Z
2015-12-28T00:00Z
2015-12-28T00:00Z
2016-12-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

The last one should be `2015-12-28T00:00:00.000Z`

```
System.out.println(d.minusMonths(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")));
```

Gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem

```
ZonedDateTime doy = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime d = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(doy.getYear(), doy.getMonth(), doy.getDayOfMonth(),0,0,0,0),ZoneOffset.UTC);

DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
builder.appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR).append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter();

System.out.println(d.plus(-1,ChronoUnit.MONTHS).format(formatter));
```

output

```
2015-12-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

So I guess Something is wrong with the pattern `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")`

Actually this formatting `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")` works

Damn it !!!!

Anyone can explain why my tests were passing yesterday and not anymore today, what's so special about January 28th ??????

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
LocalDateTime doy = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime d = doy.minusYears(1);
```

and then

```
LocalDateTime d2 = d.minusMonth(1);
return d2;
```

from API java 8 ([LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minusYears-long-)):

```
minusYears(long years)
```

> Returns a copy of this LocalDateTime with the specified number of
>   years subtracted.

and `d.minusMonth`

> Returns a copy of this LocalDateTime with the specified number of
>   months subtracted.

Comment: See the addition above

Comment: My code gets what to add or remove from a string so it's the same code doing d.plus(1,ChronoUnit.YEARS)) or d.plus(-1,ChronoUnit.MONTHS)) which anyway is not the problem here as d.plus(-1,ChronoUnit.MONTHS))  gives the same result as d.minusMonth(1)

Answer (score 2):

YYYY is year value for "year-week" style dates, as in 2006W52. It may be off the year-of-era value by +1 or -1 if the week in question straddles year boundary. Looks like you have chosen the last week of the year.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates

See also: [java.time.LocalDateTime (also ZonedDateTime). Fails to return one year backward when minus 1 month with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069998/java-time-localdatetime-also-zoneddatetime-fails-to-return-one-year-backward)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to backward one **month**, then you should do this for example:

```
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.JANUARY, 28, 0, 0, 0);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(d.minusMonths(1));
```

Comment: Actually
    LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.JANUARY, 28, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(d.plus(-1,ChronoUnit.MONTHS))
    System.out.println(d.minusMonths(1)); Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for d.minusMonths(...). I've never used the "plus" method.